# Cookie value causing a "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function menu_get_object() " error

Tags: 7, ajax, cookies

There are plenty of posts regarding this Drupal error, but my situation is quite odd indeed. Here's the background:

I was asked to investigate an ajax error popping up on a form which does an account lookup. The following is the consistent behavior I'm seeing:

1. Log into site perfectly fine and navigate to any page without issue.
2. Recreate error
3. Now ALL pages on the site error out with the error `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function menu_get_object()`
4. Attempt an Empty Cache and Hard Reload (in Chrome, by opening up the development pane and then right clicking on the page refresh icon), but nothing changes.
5. I open up an incognito window or different browser and the site is fine once more.
6. If I manually delete the site cookies, then the page is also fine again.

Something in the site cookies is clearly corrupting the session. However, I have no idea how to debug this or what could possibly be the issue. Any leads would be amazing.

Comment: If you think its a cookie then i'd use your browser to see what cookies are set once the error happens. See if there's any non-standard cookies being set. Then do a search in the site's code to look for mentions of that cookie. As this sounds like some custom code going wrong

Comment: @unusedspoon The only issue is here, when I inspect cookies, there are no new ones added once I run the code which triggers the error. It must be stored in the existing value....